# C# UDP data. how to get data back to the UI and trigger an update event

Tags: c#, callback, udp

I'm using this UDP implementation....
https://gist.github.com/darkguy2008/413a6fea3a5b4e67e5e0d96f750088a9
I wont paste the code here in case that has copyright implications.

Basically, in the Receive method, I want to get the data back to the UI (in a different class) instead of simply writing to the console and trigger an event to update the UI.

This must be a common requirement. How do I achieve something like what I want because I'm lacking imagination at the moment. I have implemented one solution I grabbed from somewhere that involves calling a public static method in the UI class but that does not feel like the right way to do it. It would make the UDP class tied to working with this UI class and surely that defeats the point of making generalized classes.

It seems easy to me to get data back if just calling methods in another class but here we are dealing with asyncronous callbacks when a UDP packet is received.

Comment: What GUI framework are we talking about?    I'd update some sort of data source which your UI elements bind to. For example some observable collection maybe.

Comment: Just a standard C# .net windows forms application.

Comment: Perfect: Update a Model and have the UI detect the change. That way, you can even debounce if needed. (That is: _not_ update on _every_ new data, if the Gui Refresh is somewhat expensive and would lead to flicker)